# Intercept tile notification inside the same app

Tags: windows-phone-8

Is it possible to intercept inside a WP8 application a notification addressed to the tile of the same application?
I know it's possible for desktop apps, but for phones I didn't find any solution.
Some other ideas would help.

Comment: What do you mean by notification to the tile?

Comment: I meant tile notification.

Comment: I'm still confused - do you mean updating the tile via: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207047(v=vs.105).aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402558(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: It's a local notification that is sent by some internal service. I want to get the same notification from within the app. Something like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709907.aspx, but for WP

Comment: I've not played with that, but maybe this can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202945(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Out of the blue: [Use a `System.Threading.Mutex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

**Application**
- Create a thread in your application that creates a Mutex.

**Notification handler**
- When a notification is handled, check if the Mutex is available (with `WaitOne(0)` it simply checks if it is available). If available, application is not running. If unavailable, the application is running (since it holds the Mutex).

Comment: But where is the tile notification handler? The notifications are being sent from another system app. I'm trying to receive the notifications at the same time **inside the application**.

Comment: I thought you meant [Push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202940(v=vs.105).aspx) but you mean [Tile notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202970(v=vs.105).aspx) then.
I suggest you took a look at [Receive push notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202940(v=vs.105).aspx): 
If you want to receive Tile notifications, you bind the channel to Tile notifications by [...].

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't intercept Tile notifications inside the Windows Phone app.

You can do with Raw and Toast notifications, using `HttpNotificationReceived` and `ShellToastNotificationReceived` events of [`HttpNotificationChannel` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.notification.httpnotificationchannel%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) respectively, but there is not similar event for Tile notifications.